# How to add thousand separator to Textfield?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've tried to add thousand separator by using **react-number-format** package. However, I couldn't make it happen. I use react 18. And this what I tried:

```
function NumberFormatCustom(props) {
  const { inputRef, onChange, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <NumericFormat
      {...other}
      getInputRef={inputRef}
      onValueChange={(values) => {
        onChange({
          target: {
            name: props.name,
            value: values.value,
          },
        });
      }}
      thousandSeparator
    />
  );
}
        <TextField
          required
          error={loanType === "I" && totalAmount > 100000}
          fullWidth
          type="number"
          label="Tota lAmount"
          value={totalAmount}
          onChange={(e) => setTotalAmount(e.target.value)}
          InputProps={{
            inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom,
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>
            ),
          }}
        />
```

Comment: What is your `react-number-format` version?

Comment: @AhmetEmreKılınç ^5.0.0-beta.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [current docs](https://s-yadav.github.io/react-number-format/docs/props) you can use `react-number-format` along with `MUI TextField` like this:

```
import { NumericFormat } from 'react-number-format';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';

<NumericFormat value={12323} customInput={TextField} />;
```

In your case, your code can be like this:

```
import { InputAdornment, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";
import { NumericFormat } from "react-number-format";

const MyNumberComponent = () => {
  const [totalAmount, setTotalAmount] = useState(52100);

  const handleChange = (ev) => {
    setTotalAmount(ev.floatValue);
  };

  const materialUiTextFieldProps = {
    required: true,
    error: totalAmount > 100000,
    fullWidth: true,
    label: "Total Amount",
    InputProps: {
      startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <NumericFormat
        value={totalAmount}
        customInput={TextField}
        onValueChange={handleChange}
        thousandSeparator=","
        decimalSeparator="."
        {...materialUiTextFieldProps}
      />
      binded value: {totalAmount}
    </>
  );
};

export default MyNumberComponent;
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-number-format-5-0-0-xjy6ff?file=/src/MyNumberComponent.js) for a live working example of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this, it works well ->

```
    export const numberWithCommas = (x: number) =>
       x?.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') || '0';
```

And to change it back to number:

```
export const numberWithoutCommas = (x: number | string, isFloat?: boolean) => {
  const str = x.toString().replace(/,/g, '');
  return isFloat ? parseFloat(str) : parseInt(str, 10);
};
```